# WebdrivermanagerException caused by due to javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, aws-codebuild, webdriver-manager

My task is to move away from managing the chromedriver version in the project so want to use WebdriverManager to download the driver based on the chromeversion present on the users machine as well as on AWS Codebuild Container.

I am new to the team and got this task to make the move.

I am seeing SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

What should be my next steps and what should i propose my team next things to do to get unblocked.

Webdrivermanagersetup code :

```
    private static void setDriver(final WebDriver driver) {
        DriverManager.DRIVER.set(driver);
    }

    setDriver(WebDriverManager
            .chromedriver()
            .capabilities(options)
            .create());
    }
```

Error Code :

```
Caused by : io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException :javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
```

I am seeing SSLHandshake exception when codebuild trying to download the chromedriver. Not sure why this issue is happening on codebuild container and working absolutely fine on the LOCAL Machine (Laptop)

Comment: The new version of Selenium has the webdrivermanager built-in.  You just need: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  and it'll run.   If you still get this exception see here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#connectivity-issues